How can I create node package that targets multiple operating system?
I have a typescript project that uses yarn to manage building and releasing. I have an odd use-case where one dependency is "windows only". I see three places this is important: source, build, and release.
Source
Branching logic:
I assume I can filter which functions to call with os.platform():
import os from 'os';
console.log(`Platform: ${os.platform()}`);

Imports
I haven't seen this kind of import pattern in typescript before, but I think I can just use os.platform() to also know when to import the windows-only dependencies.
Build
I have not found any information on this front. Optional dependencies seem to be about my only option, but they don't really accomplish what I want. It would be nice to be able to say build the windows version of this package.
Release
Node platform and architecture options can be set with environment variables and passed through our usual yarn commands, but those only seem to apply to adding dependencies.  Node OS config docs. If possible, I want to pack and publish <packageName>-win.tar.gz and <packageName>.tar.gz files to be consumed by users of the package.

You can use preinstall:
{
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node ./scripts/install-dependencies.js"
  }
}

TypeScript itself uses os.platform take a look here. You can use that to import dynamically only in windows.
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const os = require('os');

const platform = os.platform();

if (platform === 'win32') {
  // download something with execSync
}

